# How to make the blockbreaking animation smoother

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I.e. in the assets/minecraft/blocks/textures folder there are 10 textures: `destroy_stage_X.png` with `X` being `0` through `9`.

When you break a block ingame, these 10 textures are layered over the block you are mining, one at a time, according to the total amount of time you have mined (depending on blocktype and tool).

For blocks like dirt that's fine, but let's say I want to mine obsidian or something else that takes some time: how do I smooth out the animation? with the destroystages updating every second or so, that looks kinda ugly.

If I could add more `destroystages`, or make them animated, that would solve the problem - but I have no idea how (I can't just animate each using an .mcmeta file because the frametimes would be the same, regardless of the time it would take to break the specific block, resulting in a sometimes looping/cut off animation).

I know I've seen that this is possible somewhere, but that's been like 3 years and I can't find it any longer.

Comment: Pure resource pack wise? I don't think you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this using a resource pack, it is just un-achievable because of the simple fact that there are only 9 destroy stages in the texture pack, and those nine ones are the ones that minecraft reads, any other added ones would not be read, and might crash the game, you could maybe do this using other addons or mods, but as of vanilla minecraft, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to make this animation smoother. the game simply reads for files named `destroy_stage_X.png` and doesn't accept other filenames or types to replace it, and more can't be added unless you somehow crack way into the Java code itself and change how many stages the game will register (and even then it would only work for your specific client).